# how to choose the correct rest api endpoint url

Tags: rest

I have 3 collections

`Stores`

url: `/api/stores`

`Practitioners` single object has reference to store and have a schedule object

url: `/api/stores/:id/practitioners`

`Appointments` single object has reference to store and practitioner and return booked appointments

url: `/api/stores/:id/appointments`

What I want is to get available appointments times for a single practitioner but I am not sure to what endpoint url should the request be in a RESTful api way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) can be thought of as generalizations of documents.

The URL/URI is an identifier for a specific instance of the document.

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your identifiers, which means you have extra freedom in your design - you can choose spellings that are useful some other way.  The usual answer is to choose a spelling that offers a hint to a human being which document instance is being identified.

The idea being that the identifiers should make sense in the documentation, or when they show up in an access log, or in a browser history.

In your case, you've got documents that describe available appointment times, so the usual answer is to figure out what the name of that document is, then work out how to express that name using the constraints of RFC 3986.

If you've got access to domain experts, they can probably tell you what the document is in your domain.  But it might be a `schedule` or a `calendar`.

> the thing is that REST API expects you to access a collection when you reference for example /api/practitioners

That's not a [REST constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1).  `/api/practitioners` identifies a resource, and that resource supports the same semantics as every other resource on the web.

Constraints on your resource identifiers, and their representations, come from somewhere else.

For instance, JSON:API restricts [primary data](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level) to "single resources" and "resource collections" and constraints the representations of each.  Atom Pub describes Members and Collections.  [Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) generates families of related resources.

But *the* reference application for the REST architectural style is the [world wide web](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/web_arch_domain.htm).

Comment: the thing is that REST API expects you to access a collection when you reference for example `/api/practitioners` so if i use `/api/practitioners/:id/schedule` i am not sure will be correct as schedule is not a collection it is only generated data on the server and sent back to client...